# Access a field in a row based on a function

Tags: google-sheets

So, I’d like to read the value of J24, but J should be calculated. So I’m looking for a function that accept two parameters toe and column, instead of just writing J24.

GetFieldData(‘J’,24).

Comment: If I misunderstood your question, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `J should be calculated`, if you want to use `‘J’,24` as `J24` of the A1Notation, how about using `INDIRECT` as follows?

```
=GetFieldData(INDIRECT("J"&24))
```

#### Note:

- Although I'm not sure about the script of `GetFieldData`, if you want to use the value from the cell `J24` by giving `J` and `24` to the custom function, how about the following modification? In this case, `value` can be used by putting a formula of `=GetFieldData("J",24)` to a cell.

  ```
    function GetFieldData(a, b) {
      const value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(a + b).getValue();

      // do something.

    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)

Comment: Thanks. This indirect function, along with Address is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @GuyC Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.